# Making update notice functionality for my themes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created one of my themes.I want to add update functionality through api

The notice should be visible when I use the theme, if required for theme update

Actually i have no idea so please give me your suggestion or give me a code,so i can add functionality for update theme.

**Note : If you have a no idea for api so you  can provide another code**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `site_transient_update_themes` here:

```
add_filter ( 'site_transient_update_themes', 'theme_check_for_update' );

function theme_check_for_update ( $transient ) {
    // Check Theme is active or not.
    if( empty( $transient->checked['Your-Theme-Name'] ) )
        return $transient;

    $request = theme_fetch_data_of_latest_version();

    if ( is_wp_error( $request ) || wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $request ) != 200 ) {
        return $transient;
    } else {
        $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
    }

    $data = json_decode( $response );

    if ( version_compare( $transient->checked['Your-Theme-Name'], $data->new_version, '<' ) ) {
        $transient->response['Your-Theme-Name'] = (array) $data;

        add_action('admin_notices', 'theme_update_admin_notice');
    }

    return $transient;
}

function theme_fetch_data_of_latest_version() {
    // Your API call to check for new version
    $request = wp_safe_remote_get( 'https://yourdomain.com/api/upgrade-json/' );

    /*
    Response Shoul be in following format:
    {
        "new_version": "1.0.4",
        "url": "https://yourdomain.com/theme/changelog/",
        "package": "https://yourdomain.com/theme/theme.zip"
    }
    */

    return $request;
}

function theme_update_admin_notice(){

    echo '<div class="notice notice-warning notice-alt is-dismissible">
          <p>New Theme Update is available.</p>
         </div>';
}
```

Comment: I do not want to do so.

I want to do the same as it comes in Default Theme

You have any idea ?

Comment: It is the same as the default theme. If you go to the Appearance > Themes you can see the theme update notification there.

Comment: yes ofcourse you are right.

But i want to add same functionality in my theme

Comment: Replace `Your-Theme-Name` with your theme name.

Comment: Ok ok fine i am little changes in my code,it's work fine